# For which $\alpha$ does $\int_2^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln(x)}{(x-1)^{\alpha}} dx$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

So, as the title says, I have to show which $\alpha$ makes $\int_2^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln(x)}{(x-1)^{\alpha}} dx$ converge? I have really have no idea how to do this. I've managed to show that it is convergent for $\alpha >2$ but according to Wolfram, it is in fact convergent for $\alpha >1$ Does anyone have any tips or hints, to how I might go about showing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show that $\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^\alpha} \ \mathrm dx < \infty \Leftrightarrow \alpha > 1$? This one is very similar, except that you can't directly give the primitive.

Answer (score 4):

If $\alpha > 1$, then $$\frac{\ln x}{x^\alpha} = \frac{\ln x}{x^{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}}\cdot x^{\frac{\alpha - 1}{2}}} =\frac{\frac{\ln x}{x^{\frac{\alpha - 1}{2}}}}{x^{\frac{\alpha + 1}{2}}}$$

and the function in the numerator is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the fact that $\ln(x)$ is eventually smaller than any positive power.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding an integral you know converges to bound from above.  That is, if $0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$, then for any $x\in[a,b]$ if $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx$ converges, then $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$ converges.

The cases for $\alpha\geq3$ follow by $0\leq\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}\leq\frac{x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}\leq\frac{x}{(x-1)^3}$.

So $0\leq\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}dx\leq\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(x-1)^3}dx=\frac{3}{2}$.

Thus the integral is bounded for $\alpha\geq3$ by a convergent integral and hence it converges.

With a little more work the cases for $\alpha>1$ follow by a similar argument - though with a different upper bound.